# Regex: Suffix validator

Tags: regex

I need a regex which can validate a **user input** like this:

```
Jr. //Valid
Jr  //Valid
Junior //Valid
Jr.. // Invalid (1 or more periods)
.Jr // Invalid
```

Rules:
Alphanumeric characters and only 1 period at the end is allowed.

So Strings like test and test. should be valid as well.

Thanks!

Comment: Which language? Have you tried any regex expression? There's a great stie for testing regexes: http://www.regexplanet.com/

Answer (score 1):

Try this regex. It matches one or more alphanumeric characters followed by an optional `.`.

```
^[A-Za-z0-9]+\.?$
```

If you want to match sequence containing any character except `.` followed by an optional `.`, use

```
^[^.]+\.?$
```

Comment: I tried using this but it still accepts 'Jr..' as valid

Comment: @MiguelPortugal Try by adding the `^` and `$` anchors as in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
/\b(Jr\.?|Junior|\Sr.?|Senior)\b/
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:
`^(Jr\.?|Junior)$`